# Intersect operation with Flux - Project Reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Let's say I have both `var a = Flux.just("A", "B", "C")` and `var b = Flux.just("B", "C", "D")`

I want to be able to intersect both variables and the result should be equivalent of a set intersect

Something like `a.intersect(b)` or `Flux.intersect(a, b)` that would result in (Flux of) `["B", "C"]`

I could not find any operation that does this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use join, filter, map and groupBy like so

```
    //Join fluxes in tuple
    a.join(b,s -> Flux.never(), s-> Flux.never(),Tuples::of)
            //Filter out matching
            .filter(t -> t.getT1().equals(t.getT2()))
            //Revert to single value
            .map(Tuple2::getT1)
            //Remove duplicates
            .groupBy(f -> f)
            .map(GroupedFlux::key)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Results in single subscription to each and will also work with dupes.

Or you could write your own intersect method

```
public <T> Flux<T> intersect(Flux<T> f1,Flux<T> f2){
    return f1.join(f2,f ->Flux.never(),f-> Flux.never(),Tuples::of)
            .filter(t -> t.getT1().equals(t.getT2()))
            .map(Tuple2::getT1)
            .groupBy(f -> f)
            .map(GroupedFlux::key);
}

//Use on it's own
intersect(a,b).subscribe(System.out::println)

//Or with existing flux
a.transform(f -> intersect(a,f)).subscribe(System.out::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

My favoured approach would be something like:

```
Flux.merge(a, b)
        .groupBy(Function.identity())
        .filterWhen(g -> g.count().map(l -> l>1))
        .map(g -> g.key())
        .subscribe(System.out::print); //Prints "BC"
```

(If `a` or `b` might contain duplicates, replace the first line with `Flux.merge(a.distinct(), b.distinct())`.)

Each publisher is only played once, and it's trivial to expand it to more than two publishers if necessary.

Comment: Even I thought of posting this but there might be a case when `a` itself contains duplicate making this approach practically useless which also can be avoided by using distinct on each but I am not sure about its internals, it might be creating some list inside which might create memory issues.

Comment: Overall, the question isnt specific so we can only try and guess

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yup, can just add the distinct calls in if `a` or `b` might contain duplicates. You're correct in that the `distinct()` call will use a `FluxDistinct` which internally uses a collection to guarantee duplicates are filtered, so this makes it "memory hard" so to speak. If we're filtering duplicates it either has to be memory hard or re-subscribe though, not really a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

I like efficiency, so I like to use what is proven without overly depending on streaming (or fluxing) operations.

Disadvantage of this is the need to collect one of the fluxes into a sorted list. Perhaps you can know in advance whether one Flux is shorter. Seems to me however that are going to have to do such a thing no matter what since you have to compare each element of Flux A against all elements in Flux B (or at least until you find a match).

So, collect Flux A into a sorted list and then there is no reason not to use `Collections::binarySearch` on your collected/sorted flux.

```
    a.collectSortedList()
    .flatMapMany(sorteda -> b.filter(be->Collections.binarySearch(sorteda, be)>=0))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```